# gmail "or" search returns less results than one of the search terms by itself

Tags: gmail

As I understand it, searching with an "OR" condition should return at least the same number of results as each of the conditions by itself. Usually more. It should be the union of the search results for each term individually, right? However, with gmail, if I search for `label:my_label` it returns 121 conversations, and if I search for `label:my_label OR keyword` it returns 119. What's going on here?

I've tried other syntaxes e.g. `{label:my_label keyword}`, `label:my_label |  keyword`. Lowercase `or` returned far fewer results.

Comment: Ref. for posterity - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Comment: What happens if using “keyword” (in quotes) or +keyword?

Comment: @user2864740 no difference. Still 119 results.

Comment: sorry, false alarm. When I clicked through to the next page of results, the actual number was over 200 in both cases. With the "OR" the actual number was higher. It is only the initial estimate that is wrong. Should I delete this question, or post a self-answer? The weird thing is that it didn't say "about X results", so I assumed it was a precise number.

Comment: I would post an answer and explicitly call out the estimate is “off”. Sometimes it’s good to line reminded that computers are.. computers.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that gmail was just returning an initial estimate. Trying to reproduce it now, it is showing the familiar "about X results", so probably I overlooked that. When clicking through to access more (earlier) emails, the estimate increased. In the end the final number of results was over 200, and it was higher (as expected) for the search which included "OR".

One problem as I see it, is that both numbers were approximate estimates. I don't really see why the estimate for the subset would be lower than the estimate for the union. But that's probably related to the complex internals of the search algorithm. I also think that approximate estimates should *look* approximate (e.g. 100 or 120 instead of 119 and 121). But mostly I'd say lesson learnt, I will pay more attention to whether or not the result is approximate in the future.